# How to change a value color at runtime?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am developing an app using java, android studio.

I created a "myColor" style (value-> color) (eg blue) and set it in various places of my app (several activits, button, labels)...how to represent the visual identity of a particular brand, a color predominant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="myColor">#e8660c</color>

</resources>
```

My intention is to allow the user to select a color and save that color (base64, hex ...) in a txt on external storage ... and when the user opens the application again, all parts (buttons, activities) will be of the selected color.

Remembering that I know how to set the color of components in the ".setBackground" type of execution ... that's not what I want ... I want to load a color style.

Could you change a value of R.color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the colors in `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor =    getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putInt("Color", R.color.mycolor);
 editor.apply();
```

And retreive like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
int color = prefs.getInt("Color", R.color.default_color);
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Saving  resource ids is not a good practice because   resource ids change for every new build

Comment: But you can save color value in preferences.

Comment: @MysteriousGuy assuming I have an orange "myColor" color ...
editor.putInt ("blue", R.color.myColor) ... would you change the color to blue?

Comment: Shared preferences are key value pairs

Comment: First argument is key and second one is value

Comment: You need to create as many colors you want and then save the color of your choice in preferences

Comment: If I understand correctly or code just saves the color somewhere, is that it?

That's not what I need ... I need to create at runtime or change a color of R.color.

Comment: You need to understand how resource files work. The values you store in resource files are constant and final, so you cannot change them programmatically at runtime

Comment: For every color you need a separate R.color.name_of_color

Comment: @JúlioCésarBindandi please write your comment in english

Comment: @Mysterious Guy create a new can i? For example, could I leave my buttons pointing to a "myColor" that does not yet exist and at runtime create as a value for "myColor"?

Comment: No you cannot, myColor should exist with value

Answer (score 0):

Save Colour code in Internal storage or SharedPreferences and Use them by

```
Color.parseColor("#112233");
```